# Using FuzzyMatching Algorithm to determine whether there are similar words in Name column

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzy-search

I am currently having a problem of working out how to use the FuzzyWuzzy package where it identifies the 'Name' column and determines whether a similar there are similar Names. I have also transposed this document as this is the format required for a project I am creating about the GMPP data. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

The current process is placed into a data frame as I thought this would be the easiest way to go about this problem. I have tried solving straight from a CSV file also but no luck. I have also tried splitting the data into two and comparing but if the data was to be dynamic this would not achieve the objective I was trying to reach in which this process can run if further data is added.

> https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Aq_2NTfjRtf9b3L5hNHilctVQfcHynPD
>   This link has the data file and code I used

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 #Fuzzywuzzy used for string matching
 from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz 
 from fuzzywuzzy import process 

#Reading Data in and creating DB
data = pd.read_csv("data(2).csv", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
print(data.head)
data = data.sort_values('Name')
print(data.head)

df = pd.read_csv("data(2).csv")

org_list = data['Name']

threshold = 1300

def find_match(x):

 #fuzz.partial_token_sort_ratio attempts to account for similar strings out 
of order
   match = process.extract(x, org_list, limit=2, 
   scorer=fuzz.partial_token_sort_ratio)[1]
   match = match if match[1]>threshold else np.nan
   return match

df['match found'] = [find_match(row) for row in df['Name']]

print(df)
#Transposing CSV
transposed_data = data.T
transposed_df = df.T
transposed_df.to_csv(r'Desktop\Transposed_Data(1).csv')
transposed_data.to_csv(r'Desktop\Transposed_Data.csv')
```

An example of what I am trying to achieve is if a project name is called HRMC programme and another The HRMC Project I would like it to identify they are similar and put it next to each other and remove the redundant the to keep the same alphabetical format

I have also tried using term frequency-inverse document freqeuncy (TF-IDF) and was able to have some output of names but it doesn't have the full key information. It does however remove 'the' and other redundant information so would this be a way going forward?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#Fuzzywuzzy used for string matching
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz 
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

#Reading Data in and creating DB
data = pd.read_csv("data(2).csv", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
#Alphabetical Order
data = data.sort_values('Name')

#Using term frequency–inverse document frequency (TF-IDF)
#Converts raw document into a matrix of TF-IDF features
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
#Collection of text in column Name being gathered
corpus  = data['Name'].values
#Counts how many times each word existed in data set
vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
#Prints the selected column Names
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())

def ChunkIterator(filename):
#The number of rows to be read into a dataframe at a single time to fit 
into local memory
for chunk in pd.read_csv('data(2).csv'):
    for document in chunk['Name'].values:
        yield document
```

Comment: The thing you are trying to do is called entity resolution. There are tools like dedupe available which might be a better fit for your problem. I can recommend https://medium.com/district-data-labs/basics-of-entity-resolution-with-python-and-dedupe-bc87440b64d4 for an introduction. It is a bit more sophisticated than a simple partial ratio.

Comment: @maow could you provide an example as going onto this page explores how to match against 2 data sets rather than an individual column